# How to make visible and invisible container in css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I have a problem. Here you can see type switcher and containers marked by red rectangles. Every container has his own ID. When one option is selected in type switcher all other containers should be invisible. For example, when option "Furniture" is selected only last container with id "Furniture" should be visible, and all other invisible. I'm bad in jQuery at all.

[image: type switcher and containers marked by red rectangles]

```html
<form id="product_form">
  <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">SKU <input type="text" id="text-field" name="sku" style="margin-left: 37px;"/></label><br />
  <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Name <input type="text" id="text-field" name="name" style="margin-left: 21px;"/></label><br />
  <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Price($) <input type="text" id="text-field" name="price" style="margin-left: 2px;"/></label><br />
  <br />
  <label id="caption">Type Switcher<select id="productType" name="type" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <option value="D">DVD</option>
                    <option value="B">Book</option>
                    <option value="F">Furniture</option>
                </select></label>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <div id="DVD">
    <p style="text-align: left; line-height:180%;" id="caption">Please provide size in MB</p>
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Size (MB) <input type="number" name="size" style="margin-left: 2px" /></label>
  </div>
  <div id="Book">
    <p style="text-align: left; line-height:180%;" id="caption">Please provide weight in KG</p>
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Weight (KG) <input type="number" name="weight" style="margin-left: 2px" /></label>
  </div>
  <div id="Furniture">
    <p style="text-align: left; line-height:180%;" id="caption">Please provide dimensions in HxWxL format</p>
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Height (CM) <input type="number" name="height" style="margin-left: 5px" /></label><br />
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Width (CM) <input type="number" name="width" style="margin-left: 11px" /></label><br />
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Length (CM) <input type="number" name="Length" style="margin-left: 2px" /></label><br />
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Protips: Use CSS, not inline styles. That's a real pain for everyone. Also, don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not what they're for.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. You should not be posting images as answers.

Comment: More protips: IDs _must_ be unique or they don't identify anything. Repeating them is invalid HTML.

Comment: Please revise the snippet I created to show your jQuery attempt. We're not a free coding service. Put it in the JavaScript panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to learn a few about css...

```js
const
  productForm = document.querySelector('#product_form')
  sBlocks     = document.querySelectorAll('#DVD, #Book, #Furniture')
  ;
productForm.type.onchange = setTypeSwitcher;

// on init page
setTypeSwitcher()

function setTypeSwitcher ()
  {
  sBlocks.forEach( blk => 
    blk.classList.toggle('noDisplay', blk.id[0] != productForm['type'].value)
    )
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  }
label {
  display : block;
  margin  : 0;
  width   : 20em;
  height  : 2em;
  padding : .2em 0 0 0;
  font-weight : bold;
  line-height : 2em;
  overflow    : hidden;
  }
label input {
  float : right;
  width : 14em;
  }
label:after {
  content: ' .  .  .  .  .  .';
  font-weight : normal;
  }
label select,
label input[type=number] {
  width      : 12em;
  text-align : center;
  float      : right;
  }
#product_form p {
  margin-bottom : .2em;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display : none;
```

```html
<form id="product_form">
  <label> SKU      <input type="text" name="sku"   /> </label>
  <label> Name     <input type="text" name="name"  /> </label>
  <label> Price($) <input type="text" name="price" /> </label>
  
  <label> Type Switcher
    <select name="type">
        <option value="D">DVD</option>
        <option value="B">Book</option>
        <option value="F">Furniture</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  
  <div id="DVD">
    <p> Please provide size in MB </p>
    <label> Size (MB) <input type="number" name="size" /></label>
  </div>
  <div id="Book">
    <p> Please provide weight in KG </p>
    <label> Weight (KG) <input type="number" name="weight"  /></label>
  </div>
  <div id="Furniture">
    <p> Please provide dimensions in HxWxL format </p>
    <label> Height (CM) <input type="number" name="height" /></label>
    <label> Width (CM)  <input type="number" name="width"  /></label>
    <label> Length (CM) <input type="number" name="Length" /></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#productType2').on('change', (e) => {
  $('.js-modifyByType').hide();
  $(`.js-modify${e.currentTarget.value}`).show();
});
$('#productType2').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="product_form">
  <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">SKU <input type="text" id="text-field" name="sku" style="margin-left: 37px;"/></label><br />
  <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Name <input type="text" id="text-field" name="name" style="margin-left: 21px;"/></label><br />
  <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Price($) <input type="text" id="text-field" name="price" style="margin-left: 2px;"/></label><br />
  <br />
  <label id="caption">Type Switcher<select id="productType2" name="type" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <option value="D">DVD</option>
                    <option value="B">Book</option>
                    <option value="F">Furniture</option>
                </select></label>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <div id="DVD" class="js-modifyByType js-modifyD">
    <p style="text-align: left; line-height:180%;" id="caption">Please provide size in MB</p>
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Size (MB) <input type="number" name="size" style="margin-left: 2px" /></label>
  </div>
  <div id="Book" class="js-modifyByType  js-modifyB">
    <p style="text-align: left; line-height:180%;" id="caption">Please provide weight in KG</p>
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Weight (KG) <input type="number" name="weight" style="margin-left: 2px" /></label>
  </div>
  <div id="Furniture" class="js-modifyByType  js-modifyF">
    <p style="text-align: left; line-height:180%;" id="caption">Please provide dimensions in HxWxL format</p>
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Height (CM) <input type="number" name="height" style="margin-left: 5px" /></label><br />
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Width (CM) <input type="number" name="width" style="margin-left: 11px" /></label><br />
    <label id="caption" style="line-height: 180%;">Length (CM) <input type="number" name="Length" style="margin-left: 2px" /></label><br />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it is better not to reproduce the mistakes of the OP. like here the duplication of IDs,

Comment: @MisterJojo, you are absolutely right. It was my mistake. I offered one solution using classes, and didn't validate the full code of the example. I'll do better next time :D

Comment: and why not correct this mistake here?